# Load master dataset but use in multiple methods

Tags: c#, silverlight, linq-to-sql

I have a web page which contains 4 Silverlight grids. Each calls a web service which in turns uses LinqToSql to retrieve data from a SQL database via a stored proc.

The same stored proc is used and takes a few seconds to run so I thought I could somehow retrieve the data from the stored proc once and then use this "master" list of data for the other methods as a data source.

```
public class DataRepository
    {
        private DynamicsGPDataContext db = new DynamicsGPDataContext();
        List<Part> dohParts = new List<Part>();
        bool partsLoaded = false;

        private void LoadAllParts()
        {
            //all parts loaded in here and stored in dohParts
        }
```

Now, in each of my methods, I can then use dohParts as a datasource but because they are used asynchronous, how can I tell them to wait until dohParts has data?

Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One way with your current implementation would be:

```
private List<Part> _dohParts;
public List<Part> dohParts
{
  get 
  { 
     if(_dohParts == null || _dohParts.Count == 0)
        LoadAllParts();

     return _dohParts;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just noticed that this still results in the underlying stored procedure being executed 4 times, once for each method. I want the stored proc to just be executed once and the items stored in a list.

Comment: In LoadAllParts() you need to set _dohParts.  Either that or this class is getting instantiated 4 times